# Based on the code in your .h or .hpp file, what can someone learn about your app?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not sure how to phrase the question, so please feel free to rephrase it if there is a better way:
Normally code is divided between a .h and .cpp file in the following manner..

> Things like class declarations, function prototypes, and enumerations
>   typically go in header files. In a word, "definitions".
>
> Code files (.cpp) are designed to provide the implementation
>   information that only needs to be known in one file. In general,
>   function bodies, and internal variables that should/will never be
>   accessed by other modules, are what belong in .cpp files. In a word,
>   "implementations".

With reference to apps using native code (C++) submitted to the iOS and Android app stores, what information can an outsider learn by inspecting the package contents ? For example, I heard that one can discover class definitions, and function names ? This makes me think this is because of what is normally in .h files. But if function bodies are included in the .h files, will they be visible as well ? If someone is inspecting my app, does how I separate my code between .h and .cpp files affect what someone can discover ?

EDIT: There is no problem that I am trying to solve. I am just trying to learn what people can see based on what code is in my .h file.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? How to "hide" your code? That's never going to work anyway. If someone wants to learn the internal workings of your application then there's nothing you can do to stop it. How do you think all the hacks and cracks for games and programs were created? Not to mention how so many security holes are found and abused?

Comment: That's three different concepts, and three different languages. Extracting class definitions from an APK the "easy" way, for example, means the Java code. Regardless of any structure of your C++ part the "attacker" would only find the name of your exported native functions, and that because they'd be represented by similarly named functions in Java. Are you sure this is about C++?

Comment: For a good written program, the reader should never have the need to read `.cpp`. Absolutely everything should be understandable from the headers only.

Comment: Those are completely unrelated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no problem that I am trying to solve. I just read this online, and was wondering if a knowledgeable person could tell me what is visible based on what is in the .h file. There is no practical purpose for my question, besides curiosity.

Comment: @TheVee Yes - your answer is the kind of thing I was looking for. I was curious because Objective-c++ is a super-set of C++, and when you submit an app, there is an option to upload symbols for debugging. Its unclear what Xcode etc does underneath, so I was wondering if code in the .h files, somehow makes it easier for someone to inspect your app...

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this is solely focusing on the C++ part of the project and its compile options (as per the tags of the question), not the other languages.

After the compilation of your native library, there's no difference between the header and the source file. They get combined together into a single "[translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))" by the preprocessor (`#include`s literally inserted in their respective places etc.) and from that point on it makes no difference at all which line came from which file.

What is *visible* are the names of your exported functions. You can't change that, you can make the attackers' life a bit worse by giving them obscure names. And you need exported functions because they are the common language the C++ and Objective-C slash Java parts of your project share: without any interface, your native library could not be accessed in any way.

As far as code goes – as Some Programmer Dude said, if your attacker wants really bad they **will** find out what your code does. The C++ commands aren't directly recoverable (unless you compile with debugging symbols, like `-g` in GCC or Clang) the same way they are from Java, so that's a level of obfuscation, but no machine code is completely immune to [reverse engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering). If nothing else, your *processor* needs to ultimately understand the steps it is asked to follow, and you can simply simulate a processor in doing so.

TLDR: code compiled by Java is quite easy to "read", code compiled by C++ isn't, regardless of `.cpp` / `.h` separation.